# How to Access Array three-dimensional in position 2 c++

Tags: c++

I have a problem to get access to the second position of a three-dimensional array.
See code:

```
int qtdMosquitos = 2500000;

int altura = 500, largura = 500, i, j, k, qtdMosquitoPorCelula = qtdMosquitos /(altura*largura);
long id = 1;
Mosquito* mosquitos[qtdMosquitos][qtdMosquitos][qtdMosquitoPorCelula];
Mosquito* listaMosquitos[qtdMosquitoPorCelula];

for (i = 0; i < altura; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < largura; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < qtdMosquitoPorCelula; k++) {
            Mosquito* mosquito = new Mosquito();
            mosquito->setId(id);
            mosquito->setState("S");
            listaMosquitos[k] = mosquito;
         }
         mosquitos[i][j] = listaMosquitos;
    }
}
```

Line `mosquitos[i][j] = listaMosquitos;` displays the following error:

```
main.cpp|24|error: invalid array assignment|
```

I understand what error says, but I can not find the cause, we already created the instance of the 3D matrix with the same variable that is created the simple array, variable `qtdMosquitoPorCelula`.

Could you help me set a value for the 3D array?
As follows: `matrix[0][1] = arraySimples;`

Comment: You're assigning whole array to `[i,j]` position in your matrix. You can't do that like this, you have to loop over the array and copy each elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the array in C is the pointer of the first element of the array. Therefore, the code

```
mosquitos[i][j] = listaMosquitos;
```

means assigning the pointer of `listaMosquitos[0]` to `mosquitos[i][j][0]` which will cause memory issue and the compile will prohibit it.

In the code sample, we can do the same thing with the following code sample:

```
.....
for (i = 0; i < altura; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < largura; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < qtdMosquitoPorCelula; k++) {
            Mosquito* mosquito = new Mosquito();
            mosquito->setId(id);
            mosquito->setState("S");
            listaMosquitos[k]  = mosquito;
            mosquitos[i][j][k] = mosquito;
        }
    }
}
```